# How can I use Spring MVC "form" tag instead of my "input" tags?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

**What I have:**

I have a **generic** JSP page that is used throughout my application for displaying certain entities. The code that I am interested in goes like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="object"/>
    <core:forEach items="${sections}" var="section" varStatus="itemStat">
        <core:forEach items="${section.fields}" var="fieldDef">
            <form:input path="${fieldDef.fieldName}"/>                                        
        </core:forEach>
    </core:forEach>
<form:form>
```

For each section, and for each field in that section, I have an input having the path *fieldName*, which is what I want to display from each field.

**What I want:**

I would like instead of the input to be a simple text, like a label.

**What I have tried:**

I am most certain that I can do it somehow with `<form:label>` but I can't really make it work. Making a `<form:label path="${fieldDef.fieldName}" />` just tells the browser for which field I need the label, but doesn't get the actual value from it.

I have also tried something like `${object.fieldDef.fieldName}`, but in order for this to work I would have to first analyze the value of `${fieldDef.fieldName}`, which would give me the name of the column, and then do a `${object.column}`, but column being a variable I haven't been able to make this work in any way.

**Alternative:**

An alternative would be to just make the inputs as disabled and remove the border with CSS, but that would be a dirty way and from what I saw it is also tricky for IE different versions. I am sure that I can handle it directly.

---

I am a little intrigued by the fact that `<form:input path="...">` puts into the input what it finds corresponding to that path (same goes for other form elements), but with label it works different.

So, what I want is basically simple, but I haven't managed to find a way. If someone could shed some light, that would be great. Thanks in advance !

Comment: The `form` taglib is not JSTL. That's recognizeable as Struts or Spring MVC. Please read the `form` taglib URI and update your question accordingly. Also, read our JSTL wiki page to learn what JSTL really is: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the spring bind tag. I haven't tried using it before but this may work for you, in place of the input tag

```
<spring:bind path="fieldDef.fieldName">
 ${status.value}
</spring:bind>
```

reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<form:input path="${fieldDef.fieldName}"/>
```

use

```
<c:out value="${fieldDef.fieldName}"/>
```

It would display whatever value is there instead of creating a input field. Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Doing that will just print out my column name, for example **id** or **name**. I want to print the value from **${object.name}**. This is my problem. This is what I am seeking with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the spring form tab, one option would be to use

<form:input **disabled="true"**  path="${fieldDef.fieldName}"/>

To further make it not look like an input you could use CSS to style it to your preference.

Some css styles you could use:

background-color:#EEEEEE;border: 0px solid;

Update: 
 You could look into the spring bind tag.  I haven't tried using it before but this may work for you, in place of the input tag

```
<spring:bind path="fieldDef.fieldName">
     ${status.value}
</spring:bind>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post, I have thought about this but it is not a nice way to do it. Furthermore, even though it looks okay in Firefox or Chrome, in some versions of Internet Explorer the `background-color: inherit` does not really work, and some borders do not display okay. So I would like to do it in another way.

Comment: Have you looked in the spring:bind  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

Comment: Yes, yes, yes !! This is what I was looking for. Thank you, sir! If you could post this as an answer rather than a comment, I could mark this question as resolved by choosing it.